# Starting Coroutine in Main Thread

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, webrequest, unitywebrequest

So I'm trying to execute a UnityWebrequest, which needs to start from a Coroutine.
Now trying to Debug everything at some point I figured out calling the Coroutine from the Start function works (receiving the Debug.Log messages), but calling it from a normal function it will not work (I do not receive the debug messages within `GetRequest`).

Hence I think that for some reason the Coroutine is not running on the main-thread (as also no error appears).

Does anybody know how I can enforce a Coroutine to run on the main-thread or another solution to my issue?

Here you'll find the code where `WebGet` is being called from a class that is not in Monobehaviour, but the class containing `WebGet & GetRequest` is.

(Please ignore the request variable within `WebGet` this will be for a later stage.

```
 public UnityWebRequest WebGet(string url)
        {
            Debug.Log("This is the URL Get " + url);
            var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

            Debug.Log("Request URL: " + request.url);

            StartCoroutine(GetRequest(url));

            Debug.Log("After Coroutine");

            return request;
        }

private IEnumerator GetRequest(string url)
        {
            var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

            Debug.Log("This is the URL inside coroutine " + url);

            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (request.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + request.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Received: " + request.result);
            }

        }
```

Comment: `from a normal function it will not work` .. sounds like this "normal" method is not running on the Unity main thread -> I wouldn't call this normal then knowing that most of the Unity API is not thread-safe and can only be used on the Unity main thread ;) How are you calling your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Unity API can only be used on the Unity main-thread, `StartCoroutine` is one of those things.

> or another solution to my issue

If you already are on a background thread you can also simply use `UnityWebRequest.Get` without any Coroutine and just wait using e.g.

```
request.SendWebRequest(); 
while(!request.isDone)
{ 
    // depends on your use case, but in general for the love of your CPU
    // you do want to wait a specific amount that is "ok" as a delay
    // you could of curse reduce this to approximately frame wise check by using e.g. 17 ms (=> checks 60 times per second)
    Thread.Sleep(50); // checks 20 times per second
}

if (request.isNetworkError)
{
    Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + request.error);
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Received: " + request.result);
}
```

Have in mind though that your are still on a background thread and also other Unity API calls might not be allowed at this point.

---

If your method is not on a background thread in general note that `StartCoroutine` does **NOT** delay the method calling it (this would be exactly what we want to avoid by using a Coroutine) but rather immediately continues with the rest of your code.

You can of course do something like

```
var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
request.SendWebRequest();
return request;
```

without `yield`ing it and outside of any Coroutine but then it is up to you to ensure that `request.isDone` is `true` before you continue accessing and using the results.

---

> How I can enforce a Coroutine to run on the main-thread?

The alternative in order to force things happening on the main thread you can use a pattern often called [Main thread dispatcher](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher). A simplified version could look like e.g.

```
public class MainThreadDispatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Singleton pattern (optional)
    private static MainThreadDispatcher _instance;
    public static MainThreadDispatcher Instance => _instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(_instance && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    #endregion Singleton

    #region Dispatcher
    // You use a thread-safe collection first-in first-out so you can pass on callbacks between the threads
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> mainThreadActions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
    
    // This now can be called from any thread/task etc
    // => dispatched action will be executed in the next Unity Update call
    public void DoInMainThread(Action action);
    {
        mainThreadActions.Enqueue(action);
    }
    
    // In the Unity main thread Update call routine you work off whatever has been enqueued since the last frame
    private void Update()
    {
        while(mainThreadActions.TryDequeue(out var action))
        {
            action?.Invoke();
        }
    }
    #endregion Dispatcher
}
```

and then in your case you could use

```
//MainThreadDispatcher.Instance.DoInMainThread(() =>
yourMainThreadDispatcherReference.DoInMainThread(() =>
{
    StartCoroutine(GetRequest(url));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @derHugo, the first answer worked well for this problem. :D
Calling an coroutine was not necessary.

Thanks for your help.